# What is the exact behavior of Firefox on a page refresh regarding a cached asset under `Cache-Control: no-cache`?

Tags: firefox, caching, cache-control, etag

What is the exact behavior of Firefox on a page refresh regarding a cached asset under `Cache-Control: no-cache`?  Where can I find a document that specifies it?

On [MDN regarding how `Cache-Control: no-cache`  is supposed to work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Cacheability), I see that "the stored response MUST always go through validation with the origin server first before using it".  Browsers use etags for this.

(Note: `Cache-Control: no-cache` actually allows caching; it isn't `no-store`; don't want that to confuse any answers.)

I author a web site that has a ordinary `<link>` to the main css file, with `Cache-Control: no-cache`, and sometimes Firefox makes the request as specified (an "etag request") which results in a 304 usually (or a 200 with the content if not).

**But *sometimes* Firefox avoids such an "etag" request, especially when I press F5 to do an ordinary refresh.**  Chrome and Edge seem to always make these "etag requests", as I expect.

So that seems to go against MDN.  **What is the intended behavior, and where is it documented?**  And finally, is there anyway to coax Firefox into making the etag request on every F5 refresh?

Here are screenshots of the behavior: first request, and then after pressing F5 to refresh:
[image: first load]
[image: second load]

Comment: Cross-posted: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1317462